# Expectation inequality for max ratio difference when drawing marbles

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

> There are $n$ marbles in a bag. A strict non-empty subset of these are red, the rest are blue. We draw marbles from the bag one at a time, without replacement. Let $X_i$ be the proportion of red marbles in the bag before we draw the $i$-th marble. Define $$T=\max \{ |X_i-X_j| : 1 \leq i \leq j\leq n\}.$$ Prove that $\mathbb E[T]\leq f(\mathbb E[X_1])$, where $f(x)=-x\log x-(1-x)\log(1-x)$.

I think it might be easier to compute $\mathbb E[\max X_i]$ and $\mathbb E[\min X_i]$. Then $\mathbb E[T]$ is just their difference. But I'm not sure how to evaluate these quantities.

The $X_i$ form a Markov Chain, but I don't think that observation really helps in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so here's a pretty nice solution I found.

Let $M=\max X_i$, $m=\min X_i$ and $\mu=\mathbb E[X_1]$. First, note that $X_i$ is martingale, as conditional on $r$ reds and $b$ blues at step $i$,
$$\mathbb  E[X_{i+1}\mid X_i]=\frac{r}{r+b}\cdot\frac{r-1}{r+b-1}+\frac{b}{r+b}\cdot\frac{r}{r+b-1}=\frac{r}{r+b}=X_i.$$
Now the key bound is that $\mathbb P(M\geq x)\leq\frac{\mu}{x}$ when $x\geq\mu$. Indeed, define the stopping time $T$ as the first time $X_i$ either hits $0$ or exceeds $x$. Then by the optional stopping theorem,
$$\mu=\mathbb E[X_T]\geq x\cdot\mathbb P(M\geq x),$$
which implies the claim. Hence
$$\mathbb E[M]=\int_0^1\mathbb P(M\geq x)\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}x=\mu+\int_\mu^1\mathbb P(M\geq x)\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}x\leq\mu+\int_\mu^1\frac{\mu}{x}\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}x=\mu-\mu\log\mu.$$
Applying the above to the ratio of blue marbles, which starts at $1-\mu$ and has maximum $1-m$:
$$\mathbb E[1-m]\leq1-\mu-(1-\mu)\log(1-\mu)\implies\mathbb E[m]\geq\mu+(1-\mu)\log(1-\mu).$$
Hence we get $\mathbb E[M-m]\leq f(\mu)$, as required.